# SSAS Edit Dimension: Newly added data source not showing in Data Source View

Tags: ssas

Trying to add a new attribute to an existing dimension in an SSAS cube. The attribute is a FK to a named query defined in data-source-view.

I've added the relationship between the new datatable and the Dimension in the Data Source View. I can even see the attribute in the data source view pane.

However, when I open Edit-Dimension to add the new attribute so I can link it to the cube, I don't see neither the new datatable nor the relationship in the data source view. Can anyone please point to what I am doing wrong? Below are the steps I took.

```
   1. Added new data source using Named Query
   2. Double-clicked-open existing dimension
   3. Update query to retrieve new data source information. (Edit - Named Query).
   4. New attribute shows as new data table in Data Source View.
   5. Added relationship between Dimension and New data source view. FK of new attribute shows in dimension.
```

Thanks in advance.
-Bee